# animation on circleview like headspace in android

Tags: android, android-animation

i want to make a animation example on circle like head space player. i have tried a lot and i found this kind of animation in IOS which is posted below but i want to make this type of animation on Circle view in android.

i want to do this kind of animation in android https://github.com/marcusficner/MFIHeadspaceBlobView

So , any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: this is the link that i found ,and i want to do this type of animation in android like headspace link :- https://github.com/marcusficner/MFIHeadspaceBlobView